# Capacitive-load derating for bridge rectifier

Tags: datasheet, bridge-rectifier

I'm confused about the precise meaning of the derating info/graph for capacitive loads for the Visahy [2KBPxxM-M4](https://www.vishay.com/docs/89307/3n253.pdf).

[image]

I get it that the current rating for capacitive loads is less than for resistive/inductive, but what are the precise conditions for the bottom 3 curves, i.e. how should I read the "equation" or wahtever that is that I encircled with red?

Comment: It's the ratio of peak current by average current. 5, 10, 20 times.

Comment: @Janka: I would gladly accept that as answer (for points).